# Can "that is " be used to explain multiple things

Tags: word-usage

I recently wrote the following sentence in my paper, I don't know if the `that is` 
is correctly used. In other words, Can `that is` be used to explain multiple things.

> Along the similar classifications as [1-2], we mainly cover the consensus filtering approaches in four groups, **that is**, consensus on estimate, consensus on measurement, consensus on information and H consensus.

Comment: Yes, a type error, I will correct it immediately.

Comment: In addition to *that is*, you might want to consider *i.e.* and a color (:) as alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes,** "that is" can introduce an explanation that consists of a list of multiple things. That's not a grammatical problem, because it doesn't mean the same thing as "those are". Instead, it is a shorter way to say ["that is to say"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/that_is_to_say), which means the same thing as "in other words". It simply means "here's an explanation", which is why it uses the singular.